# How to compare two attribute values from the same entity in core data with swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a core data entity with 2 attributes they may contain the same data in each attribute.

How can I compare the 2 attributes to fetch only the objects that contain the same data in both attributes using core data and swift.

Comment: Anything you tried so far? Are you familiar with NSFetchRequest? Can we assume that you read [“Filtering Results”](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html) in the Core Data Programming Guide?

Comment: I use NSFetchRequest to filter by a variable, however what I want to do is to filter it based on another Attribute in the same entity being fetched.

Comment: Have you tried a predicate like "attr1 == attr2" ?

Comment: Im new to this language and Im not sure how to achieve that, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the simple way just works:

```
 let request:NSFetchRequest<Thing>  = Thing.fetchRequest()
 request.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "prop1 == prop2")
```

Or a more realistic example:

```
 request.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "dateCreated == dateModified")
```